# How to access the state inside the class function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I need to access the redux state inside that function, so I can call Translator.init(data) wherever I want to use that. But I couldn't access the state like this. I'm not familiar with class components, What's wrong here?

```
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
    import { makeSelectNumber } from './selectors';

      class Translator {
          init(data) {
            const sum = data + this.props.num
            return sum;
         }
    }

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  num: makeSelectNumber(),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Translator);

export const TranslatorService = new Translator();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you imported the correct selector?. You are importing makeSelectLocale and calling makeSelectNumber inside mapStateToProps?

Comment: yeah, that's a typo. It's makeSelect Number. If I console.log (this.props) it's giving undefined.

Comment: Call the selector by name not as a function! `num: makeSelectNumber`

Comment: No, my selector is a function. If i call the selector by name not as a function, then it's not hitting the selector even. `num: makeSelectNumber()` is hitting the selector, but i'm getting undefined for this.props.

`export const makeSelectNumber = () =>
  createSelector(
    initialAppState,
    appState => appState.number,
  );`

Comment: Okay you can also use like `export const makeSelectNumber = createSelector...` . Coming to the problem, did the reducer get updated correctly?

Comment: Did you added the reducer to root-reducer? And you can try using `https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-logger` for logging reducer state!